# $file field in lotus notes document

Tags: lotus-notes

I am working on Lotus Notes and I have a document that contains multiple files attached to it. Every attached file has a $File field in back end. I need to have attributes of $File field. Please let me know how can I get attributes of $File field of lotus notes document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get that information using the NotesEmbeddedObject class.  Here's an example from the docs:

```
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim view As NotesView
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Set db = New NotesDatabase( "SanFrancisco", "hill.nsf" )
Set view = db.GetView( "All Documents" )
Set doc = view.GetLastDocument
Forall o In doc.EmbeddedObjects
 Messagebox( o.Name )
End Forall
```

The [NotesEmbeddedObject class](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/855dc7fcfd5fec9a85256b870069c0ab/2475cdc1cef2b09285256c54004cf17d?OpenDocument&Highlight=0,notesembeddedobject) has properties you can use or you could presumably extract the file and access it from the file system to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which attributes you are after in the $File item. You can obtain some information about each attachment as Ken describes. You can also obtain some (probably less useful) information by iterating to them via the Items collection on a NotesDocument. If information obtained those ways is insufficient, you can get to the $File item directly via calls into the Notes API from LotusScript, but that is much more involved and requires unrestricted execution rights by the signer of the code, or possibly by the user herself, depending on context, I believe.

For more precision, tell us yourself more precisely what you're after. Cheers.